# How to update expiry time of session which is created using express session?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

`sessionOptions` is used to create the session in the below code. What part of the code should be modified so that the expiry time of the session can be updated for active user?

```
sessionOptions = {
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: false,
            secure: false,
            maxAge: 1 * 1 * 60 * 1 * 1000
        },
        secret: "googleAPISession",
        name: "userSession",
        saveUninitialized : false,
        store: new mongoStore({
            url:"mongodb://localhost/googleServices",
            collection : "userSession",
            stringify : false
        })
    };

app.use(session(sessionOptions));
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the session you would need to modify the userSession collection in the googleServices database. You would need to see how this data is stored to modify it accordingly.

What is often done is that sometimes new sessions are created instead of modifying the old ones. The old ones can then be invalidated or not (sometimes than can't be invalidated if they are not stored in a database) and the new session tokens are used for new requests.